# Need menu like iOS settings menu for Windows mobile 8.1

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

Am developing windows mobile app, looking for menu like iOS settings. Some menu item will end in first or second level, some may go upto three etc.

[image]

Comment: So you're looking for such a menu. What do you expect? Do you have a specific problem?

Comment: couldn't you just use a listbox with item template set to look like above.  When the user selects the item navigate to a page with the settings under the topic